# Scheme input and output

Tags: input, scheme

So my function has 3 variables (x,y,z) that store data, 
My function looks somewhat look like this, its recursive.

```
 (define (scoreboard)
  (define x (read))
  (define y (read))
  (define z (read))  
  (cond    
   [(eof-object? x) empty] ... (scoreboard)
```

Question is telling me too:
Implement a scoreboard for a Simon game. Your scoreboard should read a sequence of commands from standard input, and produce output as specified by the command:

```
score symbol number 
Record number as the score for the player whose name is symbol. No output is produced. Assume number is an integer between -999999999 and 999999999.

best symbol 
Output a line containing best symbol number where number is the best score recorded so far for the player whose name is symbol. 
Output ? instead of number if no score has been recorded for the player.

highscore 
Output a line containing highscore number where number is the highest score recorded for any player so far. Output highscore ? if no score has been recorded.

Sample Input:

score Fred 10
score Wilma 20
score Fred 20
highscore
score Betty 30
highscore
best Fred
score Fred 25
best Fred
best Barney

Output for Sample Input:

highscore 20
highscore 30
best Fred 20
best Fred 25
best Barney ?
```

Tracing the input i see x = score, y = betty, z = 30, than x = highscore and y = best, z = fred..
My question is, is it possible to make it that after i have clicked enter that x = best and y = fred, instead of the way it's doing it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. In particular, you want to ignore... some inputs? You're going to have to provide a larger input.

Comment: yes basically when i input highscore i want to ignore the values of y and z, so that best will the nxt value of x ... Is tht possible?

Answer (score 2):

Um. There seems to be a couple of faulty assumptions behind the question. Short answer "No" (though I'm sure some sufficiently clever schemer can prove me wrong), but let me take a look at those assumptions I mentioned.

#### Reading Directly into Local Variables

You generally don't want to do that. In a situation like yours, where you want complex input, you'd want to separate those concerns into two functions. One to get and organize input, and one to actually generate the scoreboard derived object. Something like:

```
(define scoreboard (x y z)
  (cond ((eof-object? x) empty) ...)) 
  ; not sure what returning the function 
  ; at the end was supposed to do

(define scoreboard-input ()
  (let ((x (read)))
    (cond ((string=? x "score") (list x (read) (read)))
          ((string=? x "highscore") x)
          ...)))
```

#### Depending on user input for formatting

Leaving it up to the user to remember what format your board uses doesn't sound like a good idea in the first place. This is a symptom of the fact that you're trying to get one function to do too much (if I'm understanding it correctly, it's trying both to accept new scoreboard entries and output a sorted board). A small amount of state might be your friend here; in order to put together a proper scoreboard, I'd set up a place to track data and provide some functions to the user to manipulate it simply and consistently (ok, I'm a Common Lisper by day, so I'd use methods, but still).

```
(define *board* '())

(define (new-entry scoreboard player score)
  (set! scoreboard (cons (player . score) scoreboard))

(define (show-scores scoreboard)
  (let ((highest (car scoreboard))
        (rest (cdr scoreboard)))
    (printf "High Score: ~a at ~a" (car highest) (cdr highest))
    (map (lambda (entry) 
           (printf "Player: ~a ~n    Score: ~a" (car entry) (cdr entry)))
         (sort scoreboard #:key cdr >))))
```

Decomposed this way, there's not really a need to read unstructured input. You use the `new-entry` function to add new scores, and `show-scores` to output the current board state. You'd probably want to decompose it a bit further than I have, actually, separating out a function for getting a sorted board and maybe for getting the top name too.

---

In response to your edit:

Yes, my comments are applicable, even with the changed parameters.

- separating input from internal logic is still a good idea
- relying on user reads as little as possible is still a good idea
- abstracting the problem properly into functions that your solution composes is still a good idea

You definitely want to keep a `scoreboard` around in some way (the best storage method left as an exercise for the reader; I use `alist`s above, but you could use a hash, or a tree, or an object/list of objects, or a pair of sequences just as well), and you'll want to implement three functions for it

- `(defun (record-score! scoreboard name score) ...)` => `nil`, *adds score to scoreboard*
- `(defun (best-score-by scoreboard name) ...)` => `(list name score)` or `"?"`
- `(defun (high-score scoreboard) ...)` => `score`

Then write a reader function that takes user input and returns formatted output of one of those operations as appropriate. You definitely *do not* want to write one giant `cond`, unless you like headaches for some reason.

Comment: Het i updated the question of what my function need's to do, is it still applicable to your method ?

Comment: My problem is for my input function, what will the parameters i need to use for those functions, since i read only one thing how will input the name and score for your record-score! function ?

Comment: Don't focus yet on the input. Tempting as it may be (after all, it comes first, right?), you really want to think first about the way you represent the scoreboard. As Inaimathi points out, you need to decide how to represent the scoreboard, and then implement functions that accept and return scoreboards. When in doubt, follow the www.htdp.org design recipe.